# How do I write a Python function capable of reading and overwriting a text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a basic chat program (Enter a given response and then have the computer output a preset response).

I have already created a function to add a input/response and the input/response is then given a randomly generated 6-digit number.

```
def ammendchatfile(item2, item3):
    trueref = None
    randomnum = False
    while not randomnum:
        idnumber = str(str(randomnumber(0, 9)) + str(randomnumber(0, 9)) + str(randomnumber(0, 9)) +
                       str(randomnumber(0, 9)) + str(randomnumber(0, 9)) + str(randomnumber(0, 9)) +
                       str(randomnumber(0, 9)) + str(randomnumber(0, 9)))
        opendocument = open("Chats.txt", "r")
        data = opendocument.read()
        if idnumber not in data:
            trueref = idnumber
            randomnum = True
        else:
            randomnum = False

    opendocument = open("Chats.txt", 'a')
    opendocument.write("%s\n" % trueref)
    opendocument.write("%s\n" % item2)
    opendocument.write("%s\n" % item3)
    return trueref
```

This stores the input, response, and ref. number in the format:

[Blank Space]
Ref. Number
User Input
Computer Output

I want to be able to search the document (from another function) by reference number and delete the ref. number, input, and output. How do I do this?

Comment: By the way, instead of generating each digit of the random number individually, it would be easier to generate a single random number between 0 and 99999999. And you don't need to convert the concatenated digits to a string again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of deleting parts of a file without rewritting the whole file